# how do I eliminate elements with certain Ancestors?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to set the value of all "CSS" elements "value" to "", here is the code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fi.FullName);
XNamespace rep = "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/8.0/";

List<XElement> cssElements =
    (from e in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf(rep + "CSS")
     where
     (
         (e.Attribute("value") != null)
     )
     select e).ToList();

//modify Attribute in elements
foreach (XElement xe in cssElements)
{
    xe.Attribute("value").Value = "";
}
```

But, I don't want to modify this one CSS, which has as ancestors "crosstab" and "style" (xml below):

```
<crosstab name="Crosstab1" refQuery="Query1">
<crosstabSuppress type="rows"/>
<style>
    <CSS value="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:'Times New Roman'"/>
```

how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: While I'm at it, instead of using `xe.Attribute("value").Value = "";`, can you use this instead `xe.Attribute("value").Remove();`? If it doesn't break your code that is. It will make the xml smaller by removing the whole attribute.

Comment: I tried that, but it breaks the Cognos report (the xml is essentially a Cognos report). Thank you! By the way, now I'm not getting them all (CSS), there are a few CSS that still match the condition, they have "crosstab" and "style" as ancestors, but they have othetr ancestors as well, now I'm looking for a way to eliminate those, in other words, to set a condition to eliminate all CSS with **only** "crosstab" and "style" as ancestors... Any ideas?

Comment: You could create a method to use in the *where* clause and send in the element. In the method, check if element has both "style" and "crosstab" and then `element.Ancestors().Any(e => e.Name != "style" || e.Name != "crosstab")` something like that. Maybe ignoring case. (Don't remember if XElement.Name is the correct property, but I guess you can find that out)

Comment: ALl other CSS had crosstabNode as an ancestor, so I changed the condition to: `(from e in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf(rep + "CSS") where ( (e.Attribute("value") != null) && !(e.Ancestors(rep + "style").Any() && e.Ancestors(rep + "crosstab").Any() && !(e.Ancestors(rep + "crosstabNode").Any())) )`. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, maybe something like this:

```
...

List<XElement> cssElements =
    (from e in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf(rep + "CSS")
        where
        (
            (e.Attribute("value") != null) && !(e.Ancestors(rep + "style").Any() && e.Ancestors(rep + "crosstab").Any())
        )
        select e).ToList();

...
```

I only added this to your `where`-clause:

```
&& !(e.Ancestors(rep + "style").Any() && e.Ancestors(rep + "crosstab").Any())
```

Comment: It makes sense, but it didn't work... I added some parenthesis too, but it still doesn't work, it reset all CSS.               ((e.Attribute("value") != null) && !((e.Ancestors("style").Any() && e.Ancestors("crosstab").Any())))

Comment: Can you provide with more of the xml? (Both values that should be edited and not.)

Comment: @MariusD, Mario, you have to take the namespace into account. Try `Ancestors(rep + "style")` and `Ancestors(rep + "crosstab")`.

Comment: Totally right, I tested without =) I have now updated the question.

Comment: Thanks! totally forgot about the namespace!.